# AWS S3 listing file without extension

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filesystems, aws-s3-client

My current file structure is

```
url/demo/file.txt
url/demo(file without extension)
```

Now when I try to list the file without extension it using prefix demo it also list the files in folder demo

Is there a way to just list a single object with demo without fetching files in folder demo

Also wanted to understand why and how does AWS allows same file / folder at same level with same name. Azure and other File system gives a conflict error

Comment: So you're using the AWS SDK for Java (guessing from the tags). Are you using the [AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3.html), that's been released in 2018? Or the 1.x?

Comment: We are using 2.x and that is an interesting link thanks @lchristmann

Comment: But looks like AWS wont support path style url's virtual style is the way ahead

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 does not use folders. Instead, the `Key` (filename) of objects includes the full path. So the first file is actually called `url/demo/file.txt` and the second one is called `url/demo`.

While the user interface presents the concept of folders, they do no actually exist. For example, you could upload a file to that `demo` folder without first creating the folder and the folder will magically appear. Then, if you delete the object, the folder will magically disappear (because it never actually existed).

If you create a folder in the S3 management console, it will actually create a zero-length object with the same name as the folder. This will 'force' the folder to appear in the UI even though there are no objects with that Prefix.

You can list objects in the specific 'folder' by specifying a `delimiter` and a `prefix`.

Comment: But in case of file without extension what will be the delimiter?

Comment: Always use `delimiter = '/'`

Comment: if we do that it will fetch the folder demo rather than file demo

Comment: There is no such thing as a folder in Amazon S3.

Comment: Here's an example using the AWS CLI: `aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET-NAME --delimiter '/' --prefix url/ --query 'Contents[].Key'` Take a look at what it outputs to see the impact of using a `delimiter`.